# Is there a way to get standard time in angular

Tags: angular

I have a problem like this. Can I get standard time in angular by giving date and time separately? it means

When the date is "2108-08-30" and time is "11.00".I want to get this time standard way.

It means I want to do something like this

```
const time="9.00";
const date="2018-07-02"


console.log(moment(date,time).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

Then I want to get time like this.

**2018-07-02T09:00:44+05:30**

Can someone help me to do this? I search for a lot of examples. But those were not enough to full fill my requirement. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your code.

Comment: not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but have you looked at this?
https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I update the question with some more examples.

Comment: If you use moment, check the parse section in their docs

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you're wanting to do?

`moment().toISOString()`

As per the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

Also, I don't think there is a `moment()` constructor that takes a date string as the first argument, and a time-like string as the second argument. Attempting this as you have done, will cause the moment instance to function incorrectly.

[UPDATED]

If you would like to provide a specific date and time to the moment library, and get the ISO representation of that, you could update your code above in the following way:

```
const time="9:00"; // Note '.' was replaced with ':'
const date="2018-07-02"

console.log(moment(date + ' ' + time).toISOString());
```

Comment: Then is there a way to do that without moment?

Comment: The thing that I have done is doing nothing. I want to do something like that. Is there a way to pass the date and time separately to function as in the example that I have put in the question. The moment() is not working as you told. Can You help me to do this in a right way if there is any possible way? Thank You

Comment: @dwp you can use this method to achieve the same result without moment: `new Date().toISOString()`

Answer (score -1):

Angular 1 Date and Time in Different Formats without Momentjs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
    $scope.datetz = new Date().toISOString()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
         <p>Date = {{ today | date }}</p> <!-- Date = Jul 2, 2018 -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "yyyy-MM-dd" }}</p>  <!-- Date = 2018-07-02 -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "HH:mm" }}</p>  <!-- Date = 00:07 -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "HH:mm a" }}</p>  <!-- Date = 00:07 AM -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "HH:mm:ss" }}</p> <!-- Date = 00:07:16 -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "hh:mm:ss" }}</p>   <!-- Date = 12:07:16 -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "hh:mm:ss a" }}</p>  <!-- Date = 12:07:16 AM -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "hh:mm:ss": "UTC" }}</p>  <!-- Date = 04:07:16 -->
         <p>Date = {{ today | date: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss": "ISO8601" }}</p>  <!-- Date = 2018-07-02 12:07:16 -->
         <p>Date = {{ datetz }}</p> <!-- Date = 2018-07-02T04:07:16.520Z -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```